# Use of socket.setReceiveBufferSize()

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm confused with the use of Socket's `setReceiveBufferSize()` from java.net.

From the API, I know that setting the receive buffer size for the socket defines (or gives a hint to) the data limit that the socket can receive at a time. However, everytime I try to read from the socket's input stream, I've found out that it can store more than what I set with setReceiveBufferSize().

Consider the following code:

```
InputStream input_stream = socket.getInputStream();
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(1024);
byte[] byte_array = new byte[4096];

input_stream.read(byte_array);
```

Everytime I read from `input_stream`, I've tested that I can actually read more than 1024 bytes at a time (and fill the 4096 byte array), as long as the sender side has already sent more than that much data.

Can anyone give an explanation as to why this happens? Am I just missing something? Thank you.

Comment: It seems suspiciously like you're trying to teach TCP your application protocol. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From the API, I know that setting the receive buffer size for the socket defines (or gives a hint to) the data limit that the socket can receive at a time.

No it doesn't. It gives a hint to TCP as to the total receive buffer size, which in turn affects the maximum receive window that can be advertised. 'Receive at a time' doesn't really have anything to do with it.

> However, every time I try to read from the socket's input stream, I've found out that it can store more than what I set with setReceiveBufferSize().

TCP is free to adjust the hint up or down. In this case, 1024 is a ludicrously small size that any implementation would increase to at least 8192. You can find out how much TCP actually used with getReceiveBufferSize().

Comment: That is exactly what I have already told you. It baffles me why you are now even asking.